# How to make method with different list object as parameter?

Tags: c#

I have little problem with `List` as a parameter I don't want to duplicate code.

```
class A
{
    public int a { get; set; }
}

class B: A
{
    public int b { get; set; }
}

class C: A
{

    public int c { get; set; }

}

class ModifyBC
{

    public void modify(List<C> CList)
    {

        //some action
    }

    public void modify(List<B> BList)
    {

        //some action 
    }


}
```

I want to make one method modify instead of two. This methods are exactly the same but parameter(`List`) are different. I don't know how to make parameter depends on object `List`.

Comment: It depends on the action you want to preform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this situation you could use a Generic type and constrain it to the parent class.

```
public void Modify<T>(List<T> list) where T : A
{
    //some action
}
```

This will allow you to pass in any type that derives from class `A`.

```
List<B> listB = new List<B>();
List<C> listC = new List<C>();

Modify<B>(listB);
Modify<C>(listC);
```

Both of these calls will use the same method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use generics to do something like this:

```
public void SomeMethod <T>(List<T> list)
{

}
```

You'd call it like this:

```
SomeMethod<int>(someListObject)
SomeMethod<string>(someOtherListObject)
```